# How to select value from array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm getting PHP array from Here Maps:

```
array(1) {
["Response"] => array(2) {
    ["MetaInfo"] => array(1) {
        ["Timestamp"] => string(28)
        "2020-04-26T17:28:14.089+0000"
    } ["View"] => array(1) {
        [0] => array(3) {
            ["_type"] => string(21)
            "SearchResultsViewType" ["ViewId"] => int(0)["Result"] => array(1) {
                [0] => array(5) {
                    ["Relevance"] => float(1)["MatchLevel"] => string(11)
                    "houseNumber" ["MatchQuality"] => array(4) {
                        ["Country"] => float(1)["City"] => float(1)["Street"] => array(1) {
                            [0] => float(0.9)
                        } ["HouseNumber"] => float(1)
                    } ["MatchType"] => string(12)
                    "pointAddress" ["Location"] => array(6) {
                        ["LocationId"] => string(28)
                        "NT_uIrE4zNUPdurm.zAQNkxHA_0A" ["LocationType"] => string(7)
                        "address" ["DisplayPosition"] => array(2) {
                            ["Latitude"] => float(52.14242)["Longitude"] => float(20.71666)
                        } ["NavigationPosition"] => array(1) {
                            [0] => array(2) {
                                ["Latitude"] => float(52.14251)["Longitude"] => float(20.71668)
                            }
                        } ["MapView"] => array(2) {
                            ["TopLeft"] => array(2) {
                                ["Latitude"] => float(52.1435442)["Longitude"] => float(20.7148282)
                            } ["BottomRight"] => array(2) {
                                ["Latitude"] => float(52.1412958)["Longitude"] => float(20.7184918)
                            }
                        } ["Address"] => array(10) {
                            ["Label"] => string(38)
                            "ulica Rynek 4, 05-840 Brwinów, Polska" ["Country"] => string(3)
                            "POL" ["State"] => string(16)
                            "Woj. Mazowieckie" ["County"] => string(18)
                            "Powiat Pruszkowski" ["City"] => string(8)
                            "Brwinów" ["District"] => string(8)
                            "Brwinów" ["Street"] => string(11)
                            "ulica Rynek" ["HouseNumber"] => string(1)
                            "4" ["PostalCode"] => string(6)
                            "05-840" ["AdditionalData"] => array(3) {
                                [0] => array(2) {
                                    ["value"] => string(6)
                                    "Polska" ["key"] => string(11)
                                    "CountryName"
                                } [1] => array(2) {
                                    ["value"] => string(16)
                                    "Woj. Mazowieckie" ["key"] => string(9)
                                    "StateName"
                                } [2] => array(2) {
                                    ["value"] => string(18)
                                    "Powiat Pruszkowski" ["key"] => string(10)
                                    "CountyName"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

To got array pasted above I'm using:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$string = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/geocode.json?&street=Rynek%204&city=Brwin%C3%B3w%20&country=Poland&gen=9&apiKey=MY_API_KEY");

$result=curl_exec($ch);


curl_close($ch);

$decoded=var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
```

I would like to get *Latitude* and *Longitude* from *DisplayPosition*.
How I can do this?

I tried:
var_dump ($decoded[1]["Response"][0]["View"][0]["Result"][0]["Location"]["DisplayPosition"]["Latitude"]);

but it won't helpt. I think I tried everything...

Comment: It's very hard to read your array. Better show `var_export($decoded)`. But your array starts with `$decoded['Response']['View'][0]['Result'][0]...`

Comment: @Justinas `var_export($decoded);` is giving me `NULL`

Comment: What is your array called?

Comment: @mrfox And what if you do `echo var_export($decoded, true);`? Does your array is named `$decoded`?

Comment: When I try `echo var_export($decoded, true);` I'm getting still `NULL`

Comment: Where do you get your output from? If you $decoded array is NULL, what array did you output (in your question) ?

Comment: I've added whole code into question few secs ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get your response as an array. You get as an JSON. As I understand it you put the response in a variable you call `$string` (based on comments to @Sacha).

You want to treat this as an array, try doing:

```
//true makes the json string into an associative arrays which
//is often needed for json responses 
$array = json_decode($string, true);
```

When you have done this, try this:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
```

My guess is that it might be something like this:

```
$latitude = $array['Response']['View'][0]['Location']['DisplayPosition']['Latitude']
$longitudfe = $array['Response']['View'][0]['Location']['DisplayPosition']['Longitude']
```

But as @Sacha mentioned, you have to check value level for level to be sure that you're on the right track:

```
var_dump($array['Response']);
var_dump($array['Response']['View'];
var_dump($array['Response']['View'][0];
```

etc...

Comment: First of all I know that array is hard to read :/ I'm getting it from [Here Maps service](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/geocoder/latitude-longitude-by-free-form-address).

$latitude is empty. Even when I shortened `$decoded['Response']['View'][0]['Location']['DisplayPosition']['Latitude']` from you into `$decoded['Response']`

Comment: Aha. This is not an array. It's a JSON-formatted response.

Comment: Arrrrr. So it looks I made nice mess here

Comment: @mrfox .- please look at my updated answer and I hope it will give you the answer you needed :-)

Comment: You saved me. Thank you so much. You resolved problem I made. Once again, thank you!

Comment: No problem. Glad to help!